# Can I claim spouse exemption for my dual status alien spouse?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tax-exemption

For the 2014 tax year my alien spouse and I (US citizen living overseas) will file 'Married filing separately' because she is making a 1040NR expatriate return, which will include f8854. She is a resident alien for Jan-Jul 2014 and a non-resident alien effective mid July 2014 when her I-407 is accepted at the US consulate.  During 2014 she will have no US source income, but will receive foreign source income throughout the whole year.  Can I claim a 'spouse exemption' on my 1040 if she does not claim a personal exemption for herself on her 1040NR?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what the [IRS pub 501](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p501/ar02.html#en_US_2013_publink1000220820) has to say on the matter:

> **Separate return**.    If you file a separate return, you can claim an
>   exemption for your spouse *only if your spouse had no gross income, is
>   not filing a return, and was not the dependent of another taxpayer*.
>   This is true even if the other taxpayer does not actually claim your
>   spouse as a dependent. You can claim an exemption for your spouse even
>   if he or she is a nonresident alien; in that case, your spouse must
>   have no gross income for U.S. tax purposes and satisfy the other
>   conditions listed above.

Since your wife does file a tax return - you cannot claim her exemption.